# Does java zmq poller provide similar way to monitor file descriptor like c++ zmq poller

Tags: java, zeromq

In zmq cpp code, poller can also monitor fd, see below

```
mFd is created with eventfd as mFd(eventfd(0, 0))

zmq::pollitem_t poll[2] = {{mSocket, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0},
                         {NULL, mFd, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0} }
while (!abort) {
    zmq::poll(poll, 2, -1);
    if (poll[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
        socket handling;
    }
    //event fd has activity
    if (poll[1].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
        process other things
    }
```

We can use below code to wake up poller to do other things as a signal, which is useful when we want to wake up poller ASAP to do something and there is no activity on the sockets. The event fd works like a pipe, one side write something to trigger a read event on poller and hence wake up poller

```
int x = 1;
write(mFd, &x, sizeof(x));
```

So is there a way for java zmq to do the above similar things? Besides socket monitoring, can we also do something like above event file descriptor? Is there an example?

Comment: in java you can use `Channel` and `Selector`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, does java has the similar channel example as simple as above event fd, it seems channel always bind port to use, this is too heavy for me, what I want is very simple without binding any port, and just as simple as write(mFd, &x, sizeof(x)); then Selector or poller can know an event is readable

Comment: a simple article you can get form [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-selector),this website has many related articles.